# ASP.NET MVC 5 Add avatar to AspNetUser

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm newbby on `ASP.NET MVC 5`, I need to modify the user table provided by the `Identity membership` to add an avatr for the user. Is there any good exmaple for doing that. thanks

Answer (score 3):

It's easy, you need to add your field inside ApplicationUser class:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
   public string Avatar { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can write an extension method for accessing user's avatar:

```
public static string GetAvatar(this System.Security.Principal.IIdentity user)
{
   // Get user's avatar
   //....
}
```

Then you can use that this way:

```
<img class="img-circle" src="~/Content/Images/UserPhotos/@User.Identity.GetAvatar()" alt="profile">
```

**Update:** for adding photo you need to add a file input tag in your view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
  <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Avatar, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <input type="file" name="file" value="" />
         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Avatar)
    </div>
  </div>
  // Other fields
}
```

Action method:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> ActionName(RegisterViewModel model, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
        var fileName = UploadPhoto(file);
        var user = new ApplicationUser
        {
            Avatar = fileName,
            // Other fields
        };
    }
   // code....           
   return View();
}
```

Upload photo method:

```
public string UploadPhoto(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
     if (file != null)
     {
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                var rondom = Guid.NewGuid() + fileName;
                var path = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images/UserPhotos"), rondom);
                var filePathToSave = "UserPhotos/" + fileName;
                if (!Directory.Exists(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images/UserPhotos")))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images/UserPhotos"));
                }
                file.SaveAs(path);

                return rondom;
       }
     return "nofile.png";
}
```

Comment: thks for the answer, but how to save the image in the register function at accountcontroller

Comment: @MoezRebai Check my answer now.

Comment: please tell me how to get the user avatar

Comment: @MoezRebai What do you mean?

Comment: I mean, we are uploading the image, and then when we need to display that image you need to retreive it using Getavatar method, so how to get that image

Comment: @MoezRebai inside the GetAvatar method you can use your context for getting the user's avatar: `.FindByIdAsync(int.Parse(user.GetUserId())).Result.Avatar;`

Comment: OK can we save the image in the database

Comment: I always get an errors that said Invalide column name